# Get TargetGroupArn from name?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

You use TargetGroupArn in a CF template for ECS services. I have a situation where the target group has already been created and I want to make this a param for the template

But those arn's are awful:

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456:targetgroup/mytarget/4ed48ba353064a79
```

That unique number at the end makes this almost impossible. Can I reference the target by name instead of full arn in the template?

Maybe i can use Fn::GetAtt here but not sure what that looks like

This doesn't work:

- TargetGroupArn: !GetAtt mytarget.TargetGroupName

I get error: `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource mytarget`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to use the available Target-group, You pass the target group name as the default parameter to the Service CF template.
2. Internally refer the default parameter as the ref to the TargetGroupArn in the Action section of the LiestnerRule It will get the target group ARN.
3. Check this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html

> ```
> {
>   "Parameters": {
>       "VPC": {
>       ...
>       "TargetGroup": {
>           "Description": "TargetGroup name for ListenerRule",
>           "Type": "String",
>           "Default": "my-target"
>       }
>   },
>   "Resources": {
>       "Service": {
>       "TaskDefinition": {
>       ....
>       "ListenerRule": {
>                   ....
>               "Actions": [
>                   {
>                       "TargetGroupArn": {
>                           "Ref": "TargetGroup"
>                       },
>                       "Type": "forward"
>                   }
>               ]
>           }
>       },
>       "ServiceRole": {
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: That gives me this error: `Unable to assume role and validate the specified targetGroupArn. Please verify that the ECS service role being passed has the proper permissions.` That is when using the default "ecsServiceRole" for the ECS service. I also tried adding the ReadOnly then the AdministratorAccess account wide policies to this role and I still get the same error.

Comment: also I'm not defining a listenerRule in the template just pointing to the targetGroupArn right under "LoadBalancers".

Comment: Listener Rule is to point to the ALB you defined. inside that you will be able to point to the Target group. And you should define default roles for the service. Plz refer this link for service role : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html .

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately with Target Groups, you won't be able to use convention to determine it's ARN due to the extra string at the end.

If the Target Group was created in Cloudformation, it's easy enough to get the [ARN output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html) by using `!Ref myTargetGroup`.

If the Target Group was created in another CF stack, try [Exporting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html) the Target Group ARN and use [Fn::ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) when creating the ECS Service to input the Target Group ARN.

```
Type: "AWS::ECS::Service"
Properties: 
  ...
  LoadBalancers:
    - ContainerName: MyContainer
      ContainerPort: 1234
      TargetGroupArn: !ImportValue myExportedTargetGroupARN
  ...
```

Comment: The targetgroup was not created with cf

Comment: In that case you'd need to pass the Target Group ARN as a parameter like Sunil V suggested